# Scikeras with multioutput

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I tried to create stacking regressor to predict multiple output with SVR and Neural network as estimators and final estimator is linear regression.

```
print(X_train.shape) #(73, 39)
print(y_train.shape) #(73, 13)
print(X_test.shape) #(19, 39)
print(y_test.shape) #(19, 13)


 def build_nn():
  ann = Sequential()
  ann.add(Dense(40, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', name="Hidden_Layer_1"))
  ann.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='sigmoid', name='Output_Layer'))
  ann.compile( loss='mse', optimizer= 'adam', metrics = 'mse')
  return ann

keras_reg = KerasRegressor(model = build_nn,optimizer="adam",optimizer__learning_rate=0.001,epochs=100,verbose=0)


stacker = StackingRegressor(estimators=[('svr',SVR()),('ann',keras_reg)], final_estimator= LinearRegression())
reg = MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=stacker)
model = reg.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I am able to 'fit' the model. However, I got below problem when trying to predict.

```
prediction = reg.predict(X_test)
```

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 19 and the array at index 1 has size 247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo the point here is the following. On one side, NN models do support *multi-output* regression tasks on their own, which might be solved defining an output layer similar to the one you built, namely with a number of nodes equal to the number of outputs (though, with respect to your construction, I would specify a linear activation with `activation=None` rather than a sigmoid activation).

```
def build_nn():
    ann = Sequential()
    ann.add(Dense(40, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', name="Hidden_Layer_1"))
    ann.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], name='Output_Layer'))
    ann.compile(loss='mse', optimizer= 'adam', metrics = 'mse')
    return ann
```

On the other side, here, you're trying to solve your *multi-output* regression task by calling the `MultiOutputRegressor` constructor on a `StackingRegressor` instance, i.e. by explicitly training one regression model per output, the regression model being the combination of multiple regression models.

The issue arises from the concatenation of the predictions of the `StackingRegressor` base estimators and from their different shapes, in particular. Indeed:

- the predictions of the `MultiOutputRegressor` instance are demanded to the `StackingRegressor` as you can see in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/multioutput.py#L234
- in turn, in a `StackingRegressor` the predictions of each individual estimator are stacked together and used as input to a `final_estimator` to compute the prediction. `.predict()` is called on `final_estimator` in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/ensemble/_stacking.py#L267 (and in particular, you can see that it is taking the *transformed X* as input).
- the *transformed X* is the result of the concatenation of the predictions of the `StackingRegressor` base `estimators`, as you can see in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/ensemble/_stacking.py#L67.

This said, among the `StackingRegressor` base `estimators` you have an `SVR()` model which is designed not to be able to natively solve *multi-output* regression tasks and a `KerasRegressor` neural network which, defined as you did, is meant to be able to solve a *multi-output* regression task without delegating to `MultiOutputRegressor`. Therefore, what happens in [`_concatenate_predictions`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/ensemble/_stacking.py#L67) is that dimensionally-inconsistent predictions arise from `SVR()` (1D array of shape `(19,)=(n_samples,)` eventually reshaped into a (19,1) array) and from the `KerasRegressor` (2D array of shape `(19,13)=(n_samples,n_outputs)` eventually flattened and reshaped into a (19*13,1)=(247,1) array). This reflects the fact that letting your neural network output layer have a number of nodes equal to the number of outputs cannot fit into a  `StackingRegressor` with another base estimator which should be necessarily extended via `MultiOutputRegressor` to be able to solve a *multi-output* regression task.

Therefore, for me, if you want to keep the same "architecture", you should let your neural network have an output layer with a single node so that its predictions can be concatenated with the ones from the `SVR` model and accessible to the `StackingRegressor` `final_estimator` and eventually delegate to `MultiOutputRegressor`.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVR

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=92, n_features=39, n_informative=39, n_targets=13, random_state=42)
print(X.shape, y.shape)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

def build_nn():
    ann = Sequential()
    ann.add(Dense(40, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', name="Hidden_Layer_1"))
    ann.add(Dense(1, name='Output_Layer'))
    ann.compile(loss='mse', optimizer= 'adam', metrics = 'mse')
    return ann

keras_reg = KerasRegressor(model = build_nn, optimizer="adam", 
    optimizer__learning_rate=0.001, epochs=100, verbose=0)
stacker = StackingRegressor(estimators=[('svr', SVR()), ('ann', keras_reg)], final_estimator = LinearRegression())

reg = MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=stacker)
reg.fit(X_train,y_train)

predictions = reg.predict(X_test)
```